# AWS Elasticsearch scale up

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm using AWS Elasticsearch Service and I'm getting a lot of `es_rejected_execution_exception`.

According to their [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-429-error-es) we should improve index performance on our application, add more nodes or switch to a larger instance type.

If I exhausted improving my application, which one is better, to add more nodes or to switch to a large instance type?

Comment: How do your elasticsearch metrics look? CPU usage, load average, disk reads and writes etc.

Comment: CPU and memory utilisation close to 100%.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja if I exhausted improving my application, which one is better, to add more nodes or to switch to a larger instance type?

Comment: @CaeVecchi elasticsearch is a statefull application, so adding new nodes is not as simple as in stateless applications, here shards on other nodes needs to be re-distribute to balance the load on all data-nodes, if you data nodes ES heap size have not crossed 31 GB and total ram is below 64GB, and your queries are more memory intensive, you can add more RAM and some CPU to your existing nodes, otherwise you should go with HS(add more nodes)

Comment: @CaeVecchi btw you should ask this question with your cluster configuration(number of data nodes, theiir RAM, CPU and heap size) and with metrics(cpu, ram, heap, GC, ES queues) etc so that I can give better solution based on these data points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and most important thing is that, `es_rejected_execution_exception` is a generic exception for all [threadpools in ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html) and whenever their queue capacity exceeds this exception is thrown and AWS docs gave the example of `bulk` queue which is mentioned under short desc as `es_rejected_execution_exception[bulk]` note `bulk` after the exception.

Please beware that there are many threadpools in ES but most important and heavily used ones are search and write(in latest versions bulk calls also uses write queue) and y**ou need to carefully look at the exception messages to see which queue is getting exhausted so that you know what you need to optimize**.

Increasing queue size is controversial topic but if you have a momentary burst of requests than you can increase the queue size, which is again not possible in AWS ES :(

You can always increase the hardware but you should find the root cause, fix them and optimise your index and search operations so that it uses less hardware and saves $$$ , please refer to my short tips to [improve search](https://opster.com/blogs/improve-elasticsearch-search-performance/) and [index performance](https://opster.com/blogs/improve-elasticsearch-indexing-rate/)